# Angular loading component from service considered as external element instead hostelement

Tags: angular, angular-directive

In my directive, there is a way to load the component from a service. while user click on outside of the component the pop-up must closed. it work by adding this code :

```
 @HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event']) outclick(e) {
 if (this.loaderConfig.action === 'click') {
  this.toggleLoader();
} else {
    this.removeComponent();
    this._loaderActive = false;
 }
```

}

But the issue is, when i click on "input" element, which is inside the loaded component as well considered as a external element and the popup getting close. How to handle this?

[Live Demo here](https://ng-run.com/edit/QTOw992Hf0YK0xTm5IXY?open=app%2Fcomponent-loader.directive.ts)

Comment: Because you have put the hostlistener on the whole window instead of the button click?

Answer (score 0):

Because your component is still a part of the `window` object, so clicking on it still emits the `window:mouseup` event. I would recommend setting a sibling overlay div that renders behind your popup, and listen for `mouseup` for that particular DOM.

Comment: Yes, I agree. problem with that approach is, when user click the some button outside, it will not work on first click, since the first click goes to layer. second click only will trigger the button click. hope you understand the issue.

Comment: Does this issue occur if you bind `(click)` to the overlay DOM, and have it invoke the closing method in the component?

Comment: on clicking on the same host element at present. but possibly if get a way to handle the issue, that will be fine.  otherwise I may need to go for new layer introduction